# JFileChooser not working when converted to .jar

Tags: java

So I'm pretty new to coding and I just started taking comp sci in school this year. In one of my programs I'm trying to use a JFileChooser and JButton so I just copied some code I found online and modified it since I don't know how to use try/catch yet:

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String path;
            try {
                path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
                path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 7);
                JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
                jf.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                jf.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                int returnValue = jf.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                {
                    int n = ptoj.convert(jf.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath(), path);
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < 10)
                        {   
                            PictureTester.split(path + "yourFile-0" + i + ".jpg", i);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            PictureTester.split(path + "yourFile-" + i + ".jpg", i);
                        }
                    }
               }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
    j.add(button);
```

The problem is when I run it in Eclipse, it works perfectly, but when I export it into a .jar file the program opens and it seems like its going to work, but when I try to press the button, nothing happens. It doesn't crash or anything, its just that nothing happens no matter how many times I press the button.

Here is the code to the class that the previous code was getting the method "convert" from:

```
public class ptoj {
public static int convert(String n, String path) throws Exception{
    try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(n))){
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
        {
            BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
            String fileName;
            if (page < 10)
            {
                fileName = path + "yourFile-0" + page + ".jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                fileName = path + "yourFile-" + page + ".jpg";
            }
            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, fileName, 300);
        }
        document.close();
        return document.getNumberOfPages();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Exception while trying to create pdf document - " + e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Could it be that your jar is being run without the permissions necessary to read your file system?

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a command prompt so there is a console for error messages? Open a command prompt in the folder with the jar file and enter:  java -jar <JarFilename.jar>

Comment: When I run it in command prompt for some reason the button works and the fileChooser shows up, but when I try to select a file the command prompt says: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\UseryourFile-00.jpg (Access is denied)

Comment: BTW I added the code for the class I'm using to convert PDF to JPG.

Comment: C:\UseryourFile-00.jpg (Access is denied) --- Is there a missing path separator (\\)after User in that path? C:\User\yourFile-00.jpg